# How to add js file in footer in drupal6?

Tags: drupal-6

i want to include one javascript file in the footer? I try like this, but its not including in the footer.

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','book') . '/js/visitsChart.js', array(
'scope' => 'footer'));
```

Please help me

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','book') . '/js/visitsChart.js','module','footer');
```